# Trying to access resources from an Application Context in Android

Tags: android, resources, singleton, android-context

I have a singleton that holds a lot of information on my App (ACCU.class).
I'm using the application context to do a single initialization and single finishing.
One of the key features is another singleton called IMCDefinition that reads from a raw resource named imc.xml. If I call the line  `IMCDefinition.getInstance(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.imc));` from an Activity Context it works. From an Application context it doesn't...
Following goes the code:

```
public class App extends Application 
{   
    public App()
    {
        IMCDefinition.getInstance(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.imc));
        ACCU.getInstance(this);
        System.out.println("Global ACCU Object Initialized");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add it in: "answer your own question" and mark it with "V" i think you can do that only the day after though. if you do it now i don't mind marking it for you :-)

Comment: I cant answer my own question for 24 hours! But thanks anyway Scriber!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! You don't get to mess with the Constructor in this class. onCreate() is the way to go. Put your code there. Forget about the question. Should i put this in a separate answer?

Comment: THANKS ...DAMN ... i spend so much time in (half an hours ;=) to 3/4 of an hours ;=))) to ******* get this ***** ressource to show *****

Comment: No problem m8. I'm guessing that it's only after the constructor being called that you have access to resource.

Comment: guess you're right ;=)) if "you" know it, it seems somehow clear, understandable ;=))))